# WebSecurity.Logout WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated == True

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

`WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` is `true` after `WebSecurity.Logout`, because the response need to be completed before a change of the property for cookie reasons. I redirect for that reason via javascript again. In the second response is often `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated == true` as well. I don't know why. Seems random to me. Any way to get `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated == false` *after logout*? Maybe it's an caching problem.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Header", "Menu", new { area = "" });}        
    @RenderBody()
</body>
```

**MenuController.cs**

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Header()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml");
    }
}
```

**Logout.cshtml**

```
<h2>Logout</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated' == "True") {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
</script>
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            Session.Abandon();

            var url = Url.Action("Logout", new { controller = "Account", area = "SomeArea" });
            Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(url);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: public, max-age=1 Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Expires: Mon, 16 Feb
>   2015 20:47:56 GMT Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:47:55 GMT Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdHNcU29mdHdhcmVcbXZjLXRlbXBcbXZjLndlYlxWZW5kb3JcQWNjb3VudFxMb2dvdXQ=?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
>   Accept Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
>   Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:47:54 GMT Content-Length: 1633
>   HTTP/200 responses are cacheable by default, unless Expires, Pragma,
>   or Cache-Control headers are present and forbid caching. HTTP/1.0
>   Expires Header is present: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:47:56 GMT
>
> HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control Header is present: public, max-age=1   public:
>   This response MAY be cached by any cache.     max-age: This resource will
>   expire in ,02 minutes. [1 sec]
>
> HTTP/1.1 Vary Header is present: Accept-Encoding  The cache MUST
>   contact the server to verify freshness unless the value of the headers
>   named match those of the request that generated the cache entry.
>
> Note: IE has limited support for Vary.  See
>   http://fiddler2.com/r/?ievary
>
> !! WARNING: Responses which VARY should specify an ETAG to enable
>   conditional revalidation requests.
>
> HTTP Last-Modified Header is present: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:47:55 GMT
>   This response did not set any cookies. This response did not contain a
>   P3P Header.

Tested with Chrome, Firefox..

Comment: This looks like a caching issue. How is the `Logout.cshtml` partial rendered? Is it from `_Header.cshtml`?

Comment: No, its from a AccountController in a different area. I redirect from _Header.cshtml to it.                         @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout",  new { controller = "Account", area = "SomeArea" })

Comment: I still wonder why there is no way to call a action without caching.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if `IsAuthenticated` and change the visibility states.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/SomeArea/Account/IsAuthenticated",
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function (isAuth) {
        if (isAuth == "True") {
            $(".auth").show();
            $(".no-auth").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".auth").hide();
            $(".no-auth").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OutputCache` attribute caches the page/response content including the outcome of the piece of code where you evaluate the `@WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` on the server side. In your MVC view the client script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated' == "True") {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

While your cached response gets sent to the browser:
(even when logged out)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('True' == "True") {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

**Conclusion:** `@WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` is evaluated only once on the server and then cached as part of the response body for each subsequent request that comes within the duration of the `OutputCache` where not varied by any parameter.

**Solution:** `[OutputCache(VaryByHeader="Cookie",Duration=1)]` or remove the `OutputCache` attribute from the controller method.

Another thing you can do is redirect to the logout page with an unique parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated' == "True") {
        window.location = window.location + '&uniqueParameter=' + GenerateRandom();
    }
});

function GenerateRandom()
{
 ...
}
```

The above will work with your current `OutputCache` attribute set to `VaryByParam`

What is your idea about using output cache like this?

Comment: Already tried all this solutions. None of these works. It should work without javascript and it not even work with.

Comment: Then another cache mechanism is causing the above? Can you show us the response content after the redirect? Is the cookie still in the headers?

Comment: Can you use the browsers developer tool to record the http headers and body and post it here?

Comment: Headers are great, but can you show us the response body? There are no cookies in these headers.

Comment: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 20:47:55 GMT This response did not set any cookies. This response did not contain a P3P Header.